# DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata overrides the PropertyChangedCallback

Tags: wpf, silverlight, dependency-properties

Does DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata() overrides the PropertyChangedCallback too ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491.aspx

> The supplied metadata is merged with the property metadata for the
>   dependency property as it exists on the base owner. Any
>   characteristics that were specified in the original base metadata will
>   persist; only those characteristics that were specifically changed in
>   the new metadata will override the characteristics of the base
>   metadata. Some characteristics such as DefaultValue are replaced if
>   specified in the new metadata. Others, such as
>   PropertyChangedCallback, are combined.